# Windows CMD - Save output to file without hiding from console

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to save the CMD output to a text file without hiding it from the console?

> `>` - this will redirect output to a file but there will be no output in the console

Answer (score 0):

In windows powershell, linux and other shell scripts you can use `tee` command. The most basic usage of the `tee` command is to display the standard output(`stdout`) of a program and write it in a file.

The syntax for the `tee` command is as follows:

```
[command] | tee [options] [filename]
```

**EXAMPLE:**

The following command prints the console output on the terminal and save it to *myTest.txt*

```
ls | tee test.txt
```

Here `ls` command gives the list of all files or directories under the current path

OR

```
df -h | tee disk_usage.txt
```

Here the `df` command gives the available disk space on the file system. The output is piped to the tee command, which displays the output to the terminal and writes it to the file *disk_usage.txt*.

**Append to File**

By default, the tee command will overwrite the specified file. Use the `-a (--append)` option to append the output to the file :

```
ls | tee -a file.out
```

You can also check this useful [link](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-tee-command/?utm_content=cmp-true) that I used as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this symbol “**>**”  and the filename at the end of the command you want to execute.

For example, If I want the file type and mapping as text file then,

```
ftype >ctype.txt & type ctype.txt
```

This will save the output in the current directory if you want to change the directory then

```
ftype >E:\dir\ctype.txt & type ctype.txt
```

Comment: This will hide the output from the console.

Comment: This will display the output in console  and save the file :
ftype >ftype.txt & type ftype.txt

This will display the saved output file only
 ftype >ctype.txt & ctype.txt